# Time complexity of a specific function big-O

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I apologize in advance if this has been answered before.

I understand that the time complexity of the following code is **O(n!)**:

```
void permutations(int n){
  if(n!=0){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      permutations(n-1);
    }//for
  }//if
}//permutations
```

Also i understand that the time complexity of the following code is **O(2^n)**:

```
void permutations(int n){
  if(n!=0){
    permutations(n-1);
    permutations(n-1);
  }//if
}//permutations
```

However i am having trouble determining what the complexity of the following code is, i suspect it is **O((n^2)*(n!))**, but i am not sure if that is correct. I would appreciate if someone could explain whether i am right, and why.

```
void permutations(int n){
  if(n!=0){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      permutations(n-1);
      permutations(n-1);
    }//for
  }//if
}//permutations
```

Comment: What did you do to try to solve the problem?

Comment: Have a look at the recursion tree: in the `O(n!)` version, there you branch once per loop iteration, now you branch twice instead...

Comment: Number of calls of `permutations(0)` for f(n) = 2n * f(n - 1) = 2^n * n!. If by n^2 you meant 2^n, then yes, you’re correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had a typo and meant **O((2^n)*(n!))**, which is the answer.

**Layman's Approach:**

Without doing a proof (I'm a bit rusty myself), consider n=4:

- At n=4, we loop 4 times, each iteration calling `permutations(3)` twice. So total of 4 x 2 = 8 calls.
- At n=3, we loop 3 times, each iteration calling `permutations(2)` twice, but at n=4 we made 8 such calls. So total of 3 x 2 x 8 = 48 calls.
- At n=2, we loop 2 times, each iteration calling `permutations(1)` twice, but at n=3 we made  48 such calls. So total of 2 x 2 x 48 = 192 calls.
- At n=1, we loop 1 time, each iteration calling `permutations(0)` twice, but at n=2 we made 192 such calls. So total of 1 x 2 x 192 = 384 calls.
- We don't care about n=0 since this is the base case.

Examining the growth in recursions, we have a single call of `permutations(4)` growing to 384 calls. Working backwards from this figure:

- 384 == 1 x 2 x 192
- 1 x 2 (2 x 2 x 48)
- ...
- 1 x 2 x (2 x 2 x (3 x 2 x (4 x 2)))
- 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1
- 2^4 x 4!

Looks like we can deduce that it is **O((2^n)*(n!))**.

---

**Solving Recurrence Relations:**

Now that I've revised solving recurrence relations using [Big-Oh for Recursive Functions: Recurrence Relations](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html) from Duke University, adapting the approach to this problem:

- Let T(n) be time to to execute `permutations(n)`, and T(0) = 1.
- We know that T(n) = n x 2 x T(n-1)

  - This is because loop n times, execute permutations(n-1) twice.
- T(n) = n x 2 x ((n-1) x 2 x T(n-2))
- T(n) = n x 2 x ((n-1) x 2 x ((n-2) x 2 x T(n-3)))
- Thus we can generalise this for k expansions as T(n) = 2^k * k!

  - We can observe the factors n, n-1, n-2, ..., 1 (at base case), this is the factorial component (k!).
  - At each expansion, we have additional factor of 2, thus 2^k.
- As base case is n=0, we have k=n

Thus **O((2^n)*(n!))**.